How can I surround multiple lines with triple quotes in PyCharm IdeaVim?
Before using IdeaVim I would just select the lines of code with the mouse and press " 3 times to comment the entire section out. I would like to be able to do the same from visual mode in ideavim.
I press v to enter visual mode at the start of the > on line 1 and select until > under line 3:
>line 1
line 2
line 3
>


Results in:
"line 1
line 2
line 3
"


I press S (capital S) surround command and press ", but it only surrounds it with one pair of double quotes and exits visual mode. So I would have to go into visual and select it all again two additional times to get it surrounded in triple double quotes.
What i want it to be:
"""
line 1
line 2
line 3
"""



How do I get it to let me enter multiple characters?
How do I create a custom macro in the .ideavimrc file to surround a visual mode selection in triple double quotes, bound to say <CTRL-">?
EDIT: i am using the surround plugin


just select the text to be quoted and pres the " three times, works in VScode.  Expect it is the same in any editor.
